# Rails RSpec request spec fails because unexpected %2F added to redirect response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, rails-routing

In config/routes.rb:

```
get 'books(/*anything)' => redirect( "/public/%{anything}" ), :format => false
```

In spec/requests/store_request_spec.rb:

```
get '/books/aoeu/snth'
expect(response).to redirect_to( '/public/aoeu/snth' )
```

This fails with:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to( '/public/aoeu/snth' )
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/public/aoeu/snth> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/public/aoeu%2Fsnth>.
Expected "http://www.example.com/public/aoeu/snth" to be === "http://www.example.com/public/aoeu%2Fsnth".
 # ./spec/requests/store_request_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why is the %2F being inserted into the redirect response and how do I prevent it?

Edit:

If I use:

```
get 'books(/*anything)' => redirect( CGI::unescape("/public/%{anything}") ), :format => false
```

to create an unescaped string I still get the same error.

Comment: %2F is the URL encoding of a forward slash (`/`). Have you tried calling `html_safe` on the string being passed to the redirect?

Comment: I did try html_safe but it did not help. This is not an HTML encoding type issue.

Comment: Ugh. I've had so many problems with bloody escaping - I'll look through some old code and see if I've run into this exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted old answer as not helpful.  This works and is tested:

In `routes.rb`:

```
get 'books/*anything', to: redirect { |params, request|
  path = CGI.unescape(params[:anything])
  "http://#{request.host_with_port}/public/#{path}"
}
```

In `spec/requests/store_request_spec.rb`:

```
describe "books globbed route" do
  before { get('/books/abcd/efgh') }
  it "routes to public" do

    expect(response).to redirect_to('/public/abcd/efgh')

  end
end
```

Run `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/store_request_spec.rb # =>`

```
Store
  books globbed route
    routes to public

Finished in 0.15973 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 15579
```

Comment: Your solution causes an error on an earlier test that has only one segment in anything. URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): /public/%{CGI.escape(anything)}. I think I need some way of preventing the input from being encoded. How do I do that?

Comment: these things can be tricky i've found myself - there's a CGI.unescape method too - you can use that further up the pipe

Comment: Thanks. I tried that (see post edit) and I get the same problem.

Comment: Working! I have edited my answer to include working code. I have also run the rspec tests and it's green

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! After seeing your answer I was able to find the documentation for that:   # http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html

Comment: Despite it being part of the documented example above, the http://#{request.host_with_port} part is not required.