# After rails 4 upgrade %2F Being escaped on the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

we are currently upgrade to rails 4 (specifically 4.2.1). On our Rails 3 version we have SEO friendly URL's that are being generated overriding the *to_param* method.

```
def to_param
[
  (city||"all").to_url.capitalize,
  (property_type||"apartment").to_url,
  [
    id,
    (self.title(:en) || "No title").to_url.tr("`","")
  ].join("-")
].join("/") 
end
```

And on Rails 3 it used to generate the following URL:

```
city/type/id-title
```

But now it's generating

```
city%2Ftype%2Fid-title
```

We can't seem to find an answer to that. It's even causing a collision with another route. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I'm including routes to make it clearer. I didn't change anything there, it was working fine before upgrade.

```
scope "rentals" do
get "/", to: "frontpage#index"
get "/new", to: "properties#new", as: "new_property"
get "/(:destination)/(:type)", to: "searches#show", as: "search"

resources :properties, path: "", constraints: { id: /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.][\/]+/}, except: [:index, :new] do
```

Comment: where are you using `to_param` method exactly? It'll be called by `url_for` method when you're trying to generate show/edit link using rails' view helper.

Comment: try a solution like this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517431/rails-rspec-request-spec-fails-because-unexpected-2f-added-to-redirect-response

Comment: I'm not calling it explicitly @Surya, just calling helpers like property_path.

Comment: @teoreda that solution seem to me like a monkey patching. Isn't there any other way to maintain my old URL's without resorting to this?